# Salesforce Integration from third party app

Tags: apex, integration, code

I'm making saleforce integration from 3rd party app, I made callout(rest API) and got  response xml schema (xsd) format.
I'm trying to generate apex classes from xsd, wsdl generation is not working because api from 3rd party app returns xml schema file not wsdl. I have no access on 3rd party app.
Can you tell me strategy how to create custom objects from this xsd (which contains metadata information)?

Comment: It sounds to me that your 3rd party app provides rest interface. In this case,  you should get request & response json formats from the admins of  3rd party app. Depending on what data you need to send in request and what you need to save, create custom objects or use standard objects.Write apex code to send json request and process json response.... Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your response, yes it provides rest API, So seems like there is no way in Apex to generate classes from xsd file, and xsd parsing is incorrect too, best way is to JSON as response.  correct?

Comment: Salesforce allows generating apex classes out of a wsdl,for soap webservices. For rest, yes, apex allows sending request to rest service & process response in json..